# PhpStorm difference in file coloring project tree and project files tree

Tags: phpstorm

I hope this awesome community can help me:

In my PhpStorm I've tweaked it so that, as a colorblind individual I can distinguish between all the different code.

I am however, unable to set the colors for the files in the project tree:

[image: Project view with colors]

My colleague said that the files on the left ARE a different color, but as a colorblind person I cannot see this difference. It does show the changed in the tabs.

Also, the folder colors do change according to the set colors.

When I then go to the project files view:

[image: Project files view]

I do get the colors correct, but then the folders aren't colorized and I've lost all project related tree functionality.

I've searched and searched and tweaked it to the best of my knowledge, but I can't seem to find the setting to change the file color for changed files in the settings.

I do hope somebody stumbled upon the same problem and found a solution.

Comment: I do know I can set the file color setting in the appearance & behaviour setting, But as the colors are a different color already, I don't understand why I would not be able to change them.

Comment: In general: the file name colors -- they represent different VCS statuses -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html. Those colors used in both editor tab & Project View panel. I'm still unsure on what exactly you are trying to ask here .. but it I see that you are using custom GUI Theme (perhaps Afterglow .. or Material UI) -- maybe they do something that prevent your desired behavior. I suggest disabling them for the moment and try to set it up using bundled Themes only (e.g. Default or Darcula f you prefer dark colors)

Comment: There's also option to adjust colors for red-green vision deficiency (if that might help): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/color-deficiency-adjustment.html